# android app development with ndk and tcc possible?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared, tcc

Is it possible to create android apps with the help of [tcc](https://bellard.org/tcc/) (tiny C compiler) ?

Normal ndk APK's looks simple zip to me.
There were only some signatures under `/META-INF` folder, dynamic *.so libraries under `/lib`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and `resources.arsc`.

```
├───lib
│   └───x86
│       └───gdbserver
│       └───libAndroid1.so
├───META-INF
│   └───CERT.RSA
│   └───CERT.SF
│   └───MANIFEST.MF
├───AndroidManifest.xml
├───resources.arsc
```

And also, it seems like gcc/clang compilers can be replaced by tcc. I got managed to compile an general *.so file with command:

```c
tcc -r dllmain.c -o dllmain.o
tcc -shared dllmain.o -o dll.so
```

But now I'm NOT sure, how gonna I compile a full ndk project by replacing gcc/clang with tcc.

Here's my dead attempt:

```
C:\Users\gray\source\repos\Android1\Android1\Android1.NativeActivity>tcc -shared -r main.c -o libAndroid1.so -IC:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r15c\platforms\android-19\arch-x86\usr\include\
tcc: warning: -r: overriding compiler action already specified
In file included from main.c:24:
In file included from C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/include//android/sensor.h:43:
In file included from C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/include//sys/types.h:35:
C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r15c/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/include//sys/cdefs.h:283: error: #error "No function renaming possible"
```

And also, I renamed `main.cpp` to `main.c` to make it work with tcc.
**main.c:**

```c
/*
* Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*
*/

#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "AndroidProject1.NativeActivity", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "AndroidProject1.NativeActivity", __VA_ARGS__))

/**
* Our saved state data.
*/
#include <android/sensor.h>

struct saved_state {
    float angle;
    int x;
    int y;
};

/**
* Shared state for our app.
*/
struct engine {
    struct android_app* app;

    ASensorManager* sensorManager;
    const ASensor* accelerometerSensor;
    ASensorEventQueue* sensorEventQueue;

    int animating;
    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;
    int width;
    int height;
    struct saved_state state;
};

/**
* Initialize an EGL context for the current display.
*/
static int engine_init_display(struct engine* engine) {
    // initialize OpenGL ES and EGL

    /*
    * Here specify the attributes of the desired configuration.
    * Below, we select an EGLConfig with at least 8 bits per color
    * component compatible with on-screen windows
    */
    const EGLint attribs[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLint w, h, format;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

    /* Here, the application chooses the configuration it desires. In this
    * sample, we have a very simplified selection process, where we pick
    * the first EGLConfig that matches our criteria */
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);

    /* EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID is an attribute of the EGLConfig that is
    * guaranteed to be accepted by ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry().
    * As soon as we picked a EGLConfig, we can safely reconfigure the
    * ANativeWindow buffers to match, using EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID. */
    eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(engine->app->window, 0, 0, format);

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, engine->app->window, NULL);
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, NULL);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) {
        LOGW("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return -1;
    }

    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);

    engine->display = display;
    engine->context = context;
    engine->surface = surface;
    engine->width = w;
    engine->height = h;
    engine->state.angle = 0;

    // Initialize GL state.
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return 0;
}

/**
* Just the current frame in the display.
*/
static void engine_draw_frame(struct engine* engine) {
    if (engine->display == NULL) {
        // No display.
        return;
    }

    // Just fill the screen with a color.
    glClearColor(((float)engine->state.x) / engine->width, engine->state.angle,
        ((float)engine->state.y) / engine->height, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
}

/**
* Tear down the EGL context currently associated with the display.
*/
static void engine_term_display(struct engine* engine) {
    if (engine->display != EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        eglMakeCurrent(engine->display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
        if (engine->context != EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
            eglDestroyContext(engine->display, engine->context);
        }
        if (engine->surface != EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
            eglDestroySurface(engine->display, engine->surface);
        }
        eglTerminate(engine->display);
    }
    engine->animating = 0;
    engine->display = EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
    engine->context = EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
    engine->surface = EGL_NO_SURFACE;
}

/**
* Process the next input event.
*/
static int engine_handle_input(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    if (AInputEvent_getType(event) == AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION) {
        engine->state.x = AMotionEvent_getX(event, 0);
        engine->state.y = AMotionEvent_getY(event, 0);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
* Process the next main command.
*/
static void engine_handle_cmd(struct android_app* app, int cmd) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    switch (cmd) {
    case APP_CMD_SAVE_STATE:
        // The system has asked us to save our current state.  Do so.
        engine->app->savedState = malloc(sizeof(struct saved_state));
        *((struct saved_state*)engine->app->savedState) = engine->state;
        engine->app->savedStateSize = sizeof(struct saved_state);
        break;
    case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
        // The window is being shown, get it ready.
        if (engine->app->window != NULL) {
            engine_init_display(engine);
            engine_draw_frame(engine);
        }
        break;
    case APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW:
        // The window is being hidden or closed, clean it up.
        engine_term_display(engine);
        break;
    case APP_CMD_GAINED_FOCUS:
        // When our app gains focus, we start monitoring the accelerometer.
        if (engine->accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
            ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor);
            // We'd like to get 60 events per second (in us).
            ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor, (1000L / 60) * 1000);
        }
        break;
    case APP_CMD_LOST_FOCUS:
        // When our app loses focus, we stop monitoring the accelerometer.
        // This is to avoid consuming battery while not being used.
        if (engine->accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
            ASensorEventQueue_disableSensor(engine->sensorEventQueue,
                engine->accelerometerSensor);
        }
        // Also stop animating.
        engine->animating = 0;
        engine_draw_frame(engine);
        break;
    }
}

/**
* This is the main entry point of a native application that is using
* android_native_app_glue.  It runs in its own thread, with its own
* event loop for receiving input events and doing other things.
*/
void android_main(struct android_app* state) {
    struct engine engine;

    memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(engine));
    state->userData = &engine;
    state->onAppCmd = engine_handle_cmd;
    state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;
    engine.app = state;

    // Prepare to monitor accelerometer
    engine.sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
    engine.accelerometerSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(engine.sensorManager,
        ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    engine.sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(engine.sensorManager,
        state->looper, LOOPER_ID_USER, NULL, NULL);

    if (state->savedState != NULL) {
        // We are starting with a previous saved state; restore from it.
        engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
    }

    engine.animating = 1;

    // loop waiting for stuff to do.

    while (1) {
        // Read all pending events.
        int ident;
        int events;
        struct android_poll_source* source;

        // If not animating, we will block forever waiting for events.
        // If animating, we loop until all events are read, then continue
        // to draw the next frame of animation.
        while ((ident = ALooper_pollAll(engine.animating ? 0 : -1, NULL, &events,
            (void**)&source)) >= 0) {

            // Process this event.
            if (source != NULL) {
                source->process(state, source);
            }

            // If a sensor has data, process it now.
            if (ident == LOOPER_ID_USER) {
                if (engine.accelerometerSensor != NULL) {
                    ASensorEvent event;
                    while (ASensorEventQueue_getEvents(engine.sensorEventQueue,
                        &event, 1) > 0) {
                        LOGI("accelerometer: x=%f y=%f z=%f",
                            event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y,
                            event.acceleration.z);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check if we are exiting.
            if (state->destroyRequested != 0) {
                engine_term_display(&engine);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (engine.animating) {
            // Done with events; draw next animation frame.
            engine.state.angle += .01f;
            if (engine.state.angle > 1) {
                engine.state.angle = 0;
            }

            // Drawing is throttled to the screen update rate, so there
            // is no need to do timing here.
            engine_draw_frame(&engine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Possibly_ you could use `tcc` but, personally, I _wouldn't_. You'll probably need the equivalent of android studio on your development machine (e.g. an `x86_64` PC). `tcc` won't save you much there. `gcc` will probably produce better code. And, many developers use studio and gcc, so it's well tested. With `tcc`, _you_ are the beta tester. It may work but may also produce subtle runtime bugs.

Comment: yes. `tcc` can't be equal to mature compilers. But I wanna be beta tester. Just try to play and hack things with it.

Comment: So **you** will be the one to answer "_Is it possible..._". -- I'd start by using GCC to make a [example] translated to C, because C and C++ are different languages. Only if this works, I'd try TCC in a next step. -- Did you consider your target's processor? You might need to cross compile.

Comment: @thebusybee Nice idea. I will try then.